# yii2 basic using nginx for rewrite url

Tags: nginx, yii2

I want to implement the following URI:

`xxx.com/user/login`

How to add try_files in NGINX? Can someone help me with this?

this is the url manager:

```
    'urlManager' => [
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'rules' => [
        ],
    ],
```

Answer (score 0):

you should write on server configuration of nginx like this

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
}
```